# Release mode still dependent on MSVCP110D.dll (C++ MSVS)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to C++ programming and had just finished making a simple calculator. I decided to share it with my friends and after several attempts figured out how to compile it in release mode. However, even in release mode it is still dependent on the MSVCP110D.dll. I was wondering if there was a way to fix this?

Comment: The only outside resources I am pulling in are #include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream> But I was under the impression that in release mode this would remove all need for outside resources and would be completely run inside itself.

Comment: You are not helping yourself, or us, by not explaining how you *know* that you have a dependency on msvcp100d.dll.  You **do** have a dependency in the Release build on msvcp110.dll, it contains the code for iostream.  You need to copy it along with your .exe, msvcr110.dll as well.  Or just build with /MT in effect, fine for simple programs that don't use DLLs.

Comment: did you try using Dependency Walker?

Answer (score 7):

1) MSVCP110D.dll is the runtime .dll for the "Debug" version of the MS C Runtime Library.  So it looks like your .exe might not have been built for "Release" correctly after all.

2) Here is information for the "Visual Studio Runtime Redistributable":

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

3) Here is more information on this particular problem:

> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/e128dff6-cef5-4a81-b6de-fcbcaa7a23bb
>
> Unfortunately the msvcp100D.dll is a debug dll and it isn't included
>   in the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistrutable package. This is becouse
>   normally debug version aren't release to other than developer.
>   Developer have installed it by default with Visual Studio.
>
> You can compile your project in "Release" so all dll which you'll need
>   will be included in the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistrutable package.
>
> Otherwise you can do the static link of all libraries(specify /MT in
>   Release and /MTd in Debug configuration into compiler options): but
>   personally I don't recommend it becouse you put in the executable many
>   information(used by the debugger) which will slow down your app.

Comment: solved for me. Came across similar problem recently. The strangest thing that my resulting DLL was dependent upon MSVCR100.dll (without 'D'), which was right because I changed /MDd to /MD, but also dependent upon MSVCP100D.dll, which did not seem right for the same reason. After long investigation I found that it depends upon preprocessor definitions. Changing _DEBUG to DEBUG solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing your issue is with dependency on the debug version of the dll & not the dependency on the dll itself.

It's highly likely you doing one of these 2 things

1. compiling with `/DDEBUG` or `/D_DEBUG` OR
2. linking with msvcpd.lib

When you compile with `/DDEBUG` or `/D_DEBUG`, and `#include`ing one of the standard C++ headers, then msvcpd.lib is pulled in `(with a #pragma(lib)`which leads to a dependency on msvcpd***.dll.

msvcp(d)*.dll is the dll version of the standard C++ library.

If instead, your issue is with a dependency on any version the dll i.e. you want to staticly link with the C++ library, then you can compile your program with `_STATIC_CPPLIB`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm incredibly new to this. But how would I go about statically linking the DLL? When I compiled it I changed the compile type from debug to release. It then created a release folder with my .exe and .cpp contained within.

Comment: @user2396111  Right click on solution -> properties, C/C++, Preprocessor-> Add _STATIC_CPPLIB to the various existing preprocessor definitions. Also when you are there, check if DEBUG or _DEBUG is already defined.

Comment: That's not it, also a deprecated option in VS2012.  C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library = /MT

Comment: @HansPassant, just wish you to know that you saved 6 hours of my life

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any additional libraries?
Maybe you have included a debug version of a dll file with your executeable.